# Get date without time from DB table

Tags: c#, mysql

So I am trying to get the date from my database table and display it in a label text.
I am using this code:

```
this.label011.Text = myReader.GetString("Registration_Date");
```

It works, but when it displays the data, it shows as EX. 2/10/2017 12:00AM.
I only wish to see the date only not time. The data stored in the table is "2/10/2017", why is it posting 12:00AM with it?

Comment: Why are you getting it as a string instead of a `DateTime`? If you get it as a `DateTime`, you can do `.ToString("M/d/yyyy")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is stored as a `DateTime`. You'll need to format it in order to display correctly

```
((DateTime)myReader["Registration_Date"]).ToShortDateString();
```

or

```
myReader.GetDateTime("Registration_Date").ToShortDateString();
```